# Implement instructions to multicycle datapath

Tags: cpu-architecture, microprocessors

I'm trying to learn some computer architecture by myself but I kinda got stuck on the datapath part. I can't figure out how to implement lui (load upper immediate) and ldi (load data immediate) to the picture below so if anyone could help me and explain the best they could I would be really happy!

Sorry if this is not fit for this forum, but I saw some other on stackoverflow.
[image]

Comment: Do you mean how to track the execution of `lui` given the schematic? If not, implementing `lui` in terms of... what? It seems all it's been already implemented there.

Comment: Oh, because the problem said that you're supposed to make changes to the figure to allow the lui and then ldi. Maybe he gave a trick question about lui...?

Comment: Oh now it makes sense! In my answer I was forced to use the ALU to shift the value, you can put a "Shift left 16" module from Instruction[15-11] into a new input in the Mux before Write Data. As always, take with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**
I'm not an EE or CPU designer.
Always ask your professor or TA for questions regarding the material of a course.

---

`lui` is encoded as

```
31       26 25     21 20     16 15                            0
+---------+ +-------+ +-------+ +-----------------------------+
|   0xf   | |  d.c. | |  RT   | |          IMMEDIATE          | 
+---------+ +-------+ +-------+ +-----------------------------+
   6 bits    5 bits    5 bits               16 bits
```

Where

> d.c. = Don't care. Any value is allowed.
>   RT = Register Target. The register to write to.
>   IMMEDIATE = The constant to load.

The *execution* goes as follows.

The instruction is already loaded into the **Instruction register**, so:

- **Instruction[31-26]**, that is forwarded to **Op [5-0]*, is *0xf*.
- **Instruction[25-21]**, that is forwarded to **Read register 1**, is ignored and as such must be any consequent data flow, **A** must be ignored, so the mux on his right must select source 0. Thus **AluSrcA = 0**.
- **Instruction[20-16]** is forwarded both to **Read register 2** and **Write register**, since `lui` only writes, the output **B** must be ignored and as a consequence the lower mux of the ALU cannot use source. Furthermore the mux before **Write register** must be programmed to select source 0, thus **RegDst = 0**.
- **Instruction[15-0]** follows various data paths. The first one is on the upper part of the schematic, it won't loop back into the register file (through **Write data**) so it can be ignored.
  The lower data paths brings **Instruction[15-0]** as source 2 and 3 of the lower ALU mux (first is sign extended, second is sign extended and multiplied by 4).
  All these paths get into the ALU, so in theory all could implement `lui` (sign extension and shift are not a problem, convince yourself of this).
  I'm believe it is more idiomatic to use source 2, so **ALUsrcB = 2**.
  The result from the ALU goes back into the mux before **Write data**, so **MemToReg = 0** and of course **RegWrite = 1**.
  **ALUop** must be the value that shifts *SrcB* left by 16.
- There is no memory write or read so **MemWrite** and **MemRead** are both 0.

The other signals are used during other stages of the pipeline, particularly during the fetch<sup>1</sup> the PC must be updated, this is covered by **PCWrite**, **PCWriteCond**, **IorD**, **PCSource** and **IRWrite**, along with the input 1 of the *B* ALU operand (the value 4).

---

<sup>1</sup> This CPU seems to have only one ALU so care must be taken to avoid stalling when interleaving different stages. Particularly the EX and IF stages cannot be performed at the same time, so either once in a while an instruction stalls or the CPU is not pipelined at all.